# C# Converting current Year to two digits

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datepicker

I'm trying to get the the last two digits of year like,
2016 to 16 only.
When you click on the `date picker` and choose a date I want to print it to a `textview` with only the last two digits of the year.

Thank you.

the last two digits are displaying when the form loads but couldn't make get it when datetimepiker value changes

```
    private void RegisterSMS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        idyr.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2);

    }

    private void regdate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        idyr.Text = regdate.Text.ToString().Substring(2);
    }
```

Comment: use `.ToString("yy")`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
yourTextBox.Text = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString().Substring(2);
```

Comment: i used that when the form loaded it works fine thank you, but when i chose another year from the datetimepicker it added the month  like 03/2015..

Answer (score 4):

You can use following approaches to get your answer;

**Method 1:**

```
yourDateTime.Year % 100
```

**Method 2:**

```
yourDateTime.ToString("yy")
```